# what do three dots(...) in c++ mean ？

Tags: c++

***for exmple:***
msg is a class whith (operator <<)
`msg << ... << args`
[source code path][1]

> what does three dots (...) imply? anyone know this, please tell me
> [1]: https://github.com/Kistler-Group/sdbus-cpp/blob/5caea3b72bf783d88c3fa36eb8cf97cc10a71170/include/sdbus-c%2B%2B/Message.h#L295

Comment: The expression as posted is incomplete; the surrounding brackets are part of the syntax; see (4) here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold

Comment: this is fold expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a template parameter pack (variadic template)

If you search for variadic template c++ you will find many questions on here related to it.

There is also en.cppreference.com.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack

Comment: You probably should mention the term "fold expression". It's version (4) here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold

Comment: Indeed if he reads the above link he will find it